# re.sub replaces only first two instances

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have found this interesting issue with re.sub:

```
import re

s = "This: is: a: string:"
print re.sub(r'\:', r'_', s, re.IGNORECASE) 

>>>> This_ is_ a: string:
```

Notice how only the first two instances were replaced. It seems that adding the [implicit] argument name for flags fixes the issue.

```
import re

s = "This: is: a: string:"
print re.sub(r'\:', r'_', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE) 

>>>> This_ is_ a_ string_
```

I was wondering if anyone could explain it or it is in fact a bug.

I've encountered this issue before with the missing argument name `string` but never for `flags` and with string it usually blows up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fourth argument to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) is not `flags` but `count`:

```
>>> import re
>>> help(re.sub)
Help on function sub in module re:

sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
    Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
    non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
    replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
    if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
    a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    a replacement string to be used.

>>>
```

This means that you need to explicitly do `flags=re.IGNORECASE` or otherwise `re.IGNORECASE` will be treated as an argument to `count`.

Additionally, the `re.IGNORECASE` flag is equal to `2`:

```
>>> re.IGNORECASE
2
>>>
```

So, by doing `count=re.IGNORECASE` in your first example, you told `re.sub` to only replace `2` occurrences of `:` in the string, which it did.